# Laravel permission denied on remote Mysql server (AWS aurora)

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have a centos EC2 with Laravel application. I also have MySQL installed on the same EC2 instance. It was working fine.

Now I decieded to move MYSQL to AWS RDS (MySQL Aurora). I can connect to AWS RDS through Heidi and query with no problem.

However in Laravel it throws exceptions.
I changed the .env file credentials for DB_HOST, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD.

See below for the exceptions:

```
1/3 PDOException in PDOConnection.php line 43:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied
1. in PDOConnection.php line 43
2. at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=correct_host;port=3306;dbname=correct_db', 'correct_username', 'correct_password', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in PDOConnection.php line 43
```

---

```
1/2 PDOException in PDOConnection.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied
```

---

```
1/3 QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

**Update**

I just reverted the database credentials in .env to my old MySQL (installed on the same EC2 instance as the Laravel application).
It works with with DB_HOST=localhost but if I use the actual ip instead, DB_HOST=127.0.0.1, it will throw the same exceptions.

Comment: In your MySQL instance do you have the user setup correctly which Laravel is using?  Also verify the host of the user as well as that's probably it.

Comment: @user3158900 please see my updated exceptions log. I can see the host, database, username and password in the error stack and they are correct. Does it maybe have to do something with the remote connection from laravel?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are running **SELinux** on your centos EC2, try switching off SELinux and test your application again. If it's SELinux that's causing this problem, it might well be because of the policy for external connection to database. You should switch SELinux back ON and enable the policy with this command.

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

Comment: And you save my day! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /etc/my.cnt like this:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0 # will accept requests from all IPs
```

Then in your mysql add a user and give him the proper permissions

```
grant all privileges on db_name.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

This enables the user to connect to the database from any IP

```
grant all privileges on db_name.* to 'username'@'your_ip' identified by 'password';
```

This enables the user to connect to the database from only one IP. This is the best practice, you don't want to allow connections from any IP, this is a bad security practice.

This will enable you to connect to the database from your external IP

Why your RDB instance is not working is not totaly clear, have you enabled remote connections?

Comment: Hi, except first part I have already done all parts. My aws rds is accepting connection. I am using Heidi (MySQL windows client app) and its working fine. It looks like its laravel problem. Laravel is not accepting any other connection than localhost not even 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Can you post the output of `select user,host from mysql.user;` and `show grants for 'root'@'%';` and your ´config/database.php`
This is strange behaviour ideed. 9/10 it has something to do with database permissions and mysql not listening on 127.0.0.1, I think, but I can be wrong, that laravel tries to connect over the mysql socket when connecting trough localhost.