# Accessing a remote database is giving an error on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, connection, laravel-7

I'm trying to access a database (which exists on a different server) on my Laravel application. I keep getting the following error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied

My **.env** file is set up as follows (changed a bit to protect privacy):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST= IP_ADDRESS
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DB_NAME
DB_USERNAME="laravel_user"
DB_PASSWORD="password"
```

I'm not sure if this is important or not but I can access the web server's database if I go to the link **IP.ADDRESS/phpmyadmin**

My **web.php** file is as follows:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    return DB::select("select * from umts_list");
});
```

Additionally, I also went to IP_ADDRESS/phpmyadmin (where my database exists) and added a new user called laravel_user with the ability to SELECT all data and saved it with the 'password' as its password.

My attempt: I tried whatever I mentioned above and also cleared the cache since I made changes to the .env file by entering the following commands:

```
php artisan config: clear 
php artisan cache: clear
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit 1: On phpMyAdmin, I made sure to add the user as depicted by the following picture:
[PhpMyAdmin User Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAX4n.png)

Additionally, I also checked the port number on phpMyadmin and it is 3306 as depicted by the following image:
[Port Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJMhH.png)

Comment: Make sure there's no space before your IP_ADDRESS and that the MySQL user you are trying to connect with has appropriate permission to connect from a remote host

Comment: "_...IP_ADDRESS/phpmyadmin (where my database exists)..._" That's not where your database exists, phpMyAdmin is "only" a GUI tool that connects to your MySQL server

Comment: @brombeer thank you for your response. I did remove the space and I see. IP_ADDRESS points to a web application and the database exists on that server. I assumed using just the IP_ADDRESS would be enough, but I guess not. Where would I find the path and then does that mean I add that path to DB_HOST in the .env file?

Comment: You just use the IP address and the port (with the correct credentials) to connect

Comment: @brombeer yes, I did initially have just the IP.ADDRESS in DB_HOST but the error message doesn't change.

Comment: You're confused about the difference between DATABASE_URL and DB_HOST. You shouldn't need database url. Just `DB_HOST=ip`. Database url is just a concatenation of hose and port (for example localhost:5432), so it's just another format. Just fill out DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD. Make sure you're able to access the database from YOUR ip (not through phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin is just your server accessing to itself (localhost) ). If that doesn't work, make a SSH tunnel to the server or add your ip to the white list

Comment: @IGP, thank you. This is really helpful. I originally did just have the `DB_HOST=IP.ADDRESS` in just the .env file and made sure to check again but I seem to receive the same error. I'll look into creating an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case anyone else stumbles upon this post in the future, it turns out that I did not have to create an SSH tunnel or whitelist the IP. The problem was actually with SELinux. This post was the solution: [Laravel permission denied on remote Mysql server (AWS aurora)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937925/laravel-permission-denied-on-remote-mysql-server-aws-aurora)

Specifically, I ran the command: `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1`

This worked perfectly and it was actually blocking connection to remote databases.