# How to connect Remote Database in Laravel App?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

I am using **Laravel 8** and I am working on **Local environment** and I want to use **Remote Database in my Local Laravel App**. I am using **Bluehost** I have created database and generate credentials for database but when I use query I face following issue.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ngtonlin_cron_jobs_test'@'Shared IP Address.braintel.net.pk' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

I also added credentials in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=Shared IP Address
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=user_name
DB_PASSWORD="D$8]!2?^kg(!"
```

I have added below code for querying.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
dd($users);
});
```

Comment: double check the ip, really. also, try to connect from outside of the hosting if its allowed.

Comment: How can I check hosting allow outside of it?

Comment: You should add your ip to allow access

Comment: ask bluehost. this is more of bluehost problem than laravel, or even programming.

Comment: Ok Thanks alot let me check

Comment: Do you have access to the bluehost ACC or cPanel?

Comment: Dream Bold Yes I have

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937925/laravel-permission-denied-on-remote-mysql-server-aws-aurora

Comment: this might be the solution for your question if i am not getting it wrong.

Comment: https://youtu.be/7Ld4FnqiT84 @Dilshad Here's how to add your IP on bluehost remote db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add your current IP to access the database on Bluehost. You can read more about it [here](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/remote-database-connection-setup)

Comment: Ok Thanks let me check

Comment: https://youtu.be/7Ld4FnqiT84 You can check this video as well to see how to add your IP